# I want to scrape data within a local web directory

Tags: javascript, php, html, strip-tags

All the pages are connected via some `href` elements. The very first page is named `mainpage.html`. Now I want to remove the `<image>` tags from all the webpages 
and show elements within `<div id = "pB">`.

Instead of removing image tags manually from one page to another, I'd like a generic method for this purpose. Any suggestions or queries from me you can ask me, thanks in advance.

the structure of tree is

```
<html> -> <body> -> <div id= pB>
```

Comment: use php for this technique

Comment: maybe adjust http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#86964 - but im not sure i fully understand your request

Comment: i just want to perform this action for all webpages

Comment: how to reference all the pages in a single code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the structure and aim of your project are not totally clear to me, i will try to give you some hints for the various aspects i can identify. I am assuming a solution in PHP.

find all pages from within your mainpage.html:
[Regexp for extracting all links and anchor texts from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624848/regexp-for-extracting-all-links-and-anchor-texts-from-html)

or even more elegant

[Regexp for extracting all links and anchor texts from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624848/regexp-for-extracting-all-links-and-anchor-texts-from-html)

alternatively, you mentioned a "local web directory" so you could also get all files via

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Assuming you have all the filenames of files you want to parse in an $array, you could iterate over that array, open each file and use the mentioned modification from here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#86964

Either you then save your modified pages or you display them in your div.

Hope this helps a bit.