# Match if string is there in anchor tag

Tags: php, regex, match

I want to test if string is there between anchor tags, for example :
    this is example text `<a href=""> this is test string </a>` and here is other anchor tag `<a href=""> link again </a>` thanks.

In above string I want to match if "test" is there between anchors tags. how can I do it with regular expression.

Kindly help !

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regexp for extracting all links and anchor texts from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624848/regexp-for-extracting-all-links-and-anchor-texts-from-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
$x='<a href="">This is a test string</a>';

if(preg_match_all('~<a href="">.+test.+</a>~i',$x,$m))
{echo "Match";}
else
{echo "No match";}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function you can use:

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
$str = '<a href=""> this is test string </a>';
$txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "a");

echo $txt;
// Will return " this is test string ".
```

Comment: but string may have lot of data.. in a big string there are few anchors tags and among that anchor tags i need to find. so that case it may not work.

Comment: thank you Jeremy for your prompt reply.. and its a good answer.. but in case I have multiple anchor tags in a string then I wanted to know. that too  not full text only a word I need.

Comment: You really wanted to match "test", sorry I though it was an example ;)