# Walking thru HTML in PHP

Tags: php

Here is what I have so far:

My string:

```
$str = "<ul>
<li><a name="valuehere1" title="titlehere" href="/channel/london/">Link1</a></li>
<li><a name="valuehere2" title="titlehere" href="/channel/games/">Link1</a></li>
<li><a name="valuehere3" title="titlehere" href="/channel/sport/">Link1</a></li>
</ul>";
```

My PHP so far (and I am stuck):

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$children = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li')->item(0)->childNodes->getAttribute('name'); 
$out = array();
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $out[] = $dom->saveXML($child);
}
```

I am trying to extract the NAME attribute value of the A tag in the LI base on a match (in this example they are "london", "games", "sport") . WHen I pass "games" it should give me the output as "valuehere2". This has to be done at the server side due to some restrictions I have. Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks,
L

Comment: Your string has double quotes in it - escape them by making them: \"

Comment: why are you fetching the li first, when you want the a elements? Why dont you fetch the a elements directly? Or use XPath to fetch the name attributes of those a elements directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(PHP5) Extracting a title tag and RSS feed address from HTML using PHP DOM or Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054347/php5-extracting-a-title-tag-and-rss-feed-address-from-html-using-php-dom-or-reg) - covers the same grounds and shows how to do it with XPath.

Comment: and also possible duplicate of [php regular expression to match specific url pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532358/php-regular-expression-to-match-specific-url-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions to the rescue?

```
[~]%  cat test.php
<?php

$str = '<ul>
<li><a name="valuehere1" title="titlehere" href="/channel/london/">Link1</a></li>
<li><a name="valuehere2" title="titlehere" href="/channel/games/">Link1</a></li>
<li><a name="valuehere3" title="titlehere" href="/channel/sport/">Link1</a></li>
</ul>';

preg_match_all('/<li><a name="(.*)" title/', $str, $m);

print_r($m);

?>

[~]% php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <li><a name="valuehere1" title
            [1] => <li><a name="valuehere2" title
            [2] => <li><a name="valuehere3" title
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => valuehere1
            [1] => valuehere2
            [2] => valuehere3
        )

)
```

Comment: Gah. parsing HTML with regexes. horrible horrible horrible.

Comment: It depends on the context and what exactly you're parsing ... The question is posted without context, so I don't know which solution is best in this case (I assume that the $str posted is just a snippet from a larger page?), but I certainly wouldn't say that extracting data from HTML using the DOM is "horrible horrible horrible" ;-) IMHO both methods have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks CS, I have built on your suggestion and it fits well into my space. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it. But your code is fetching an attribute of the first `li` it finds, and tries to use that attribute value as an array to loop on. What you want is:

```
$children = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
$out = array();
foreach ($children as $child) {
    if ($child->item(0)->childNodes->getAttribute('name')) {
        $out[] = $dom->saveXML($child);
    }
}
```

getElementsByTagName returns an DOMElementList (or whatever), which is an iterable array. Doing the getAttribute() stuff simply returns a string.

Comment: `getElementByTagName` returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), which is not an array but an object. [`childNodes`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) is a `DOMNodeList`, too and it has no `getAttribute` method. The code cannot work.